# How to Insert into Object Table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Here I have a table which reference two object tables, up to this point there are no errors:

```
CREATE TABLE venues (
venue_id             NUMBER(6),
venue_name           VARCHAR2(30),
address              REF address_type SCOPE IS addresses,
venue_type           REF venue_type SCOPE IS venue_table_type,
provision            provision_table_type)
NESTED TABLE provision STORE AS provision_table;
```

However once I try to INSERT into this table using this command:

```
    INSERT INTO venues (venue_id, venue_name, address, venue_type, provision)
VALUES (seq_venues.NEXTVAL, 'O2', address_type('PENINSULA SQUARE', 'LONDON', 'LONDON', 'SE10 0DX'),
 venue_type(20000, 'A MULTI-PURPOSE INDOOR ARENA LOCATED IN THE CENTRE OF LONDON.'),
    provision_table_type(
    provision_type('BBQ'),
    provision_type('RESTAURANTS'),
    provision_type('TOILETS')));
```

I get the following error:

ERROR at line 2:
inconsistent dataptypes: expected REF SYS.ADDRESS_TYPE got SYS.ADDRESS_TYPE

I guess I'm inserting into a referenced object table incorrectly and would appreciate some guidance on the correct way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please tag this with the actual DBMS you are using? `SQL` is just a language.

Answer (score 0):

A `REF` must refer to an existing row in a table.  For example:

```
create type address_type is object (a number);
create table addresses of address_type;
insert into addresses values(address_type(1));
commit;

create table venues
(
    venue_name VARCHAR2(30),
    address    REF address_type SCOPE IS addresses
);

insert into venues
values('Name', (select ref(addresses) from addresses addresses where a = 1));
```